# Periodic table tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, pgfplots

Anybody knows how to reproduce this table in latex?

[image]

Thanks in advance for your time and advice.

Comment: See here, for example: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/periodic-table-of-chemical-elements/

Comment: On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Note that in my view I ought not answer do-it-for-mes. Even if somebody else already has.

This turns [Enrico Maria De Angelis's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339005/) into a `pic`, `element` and then uses a couple of loops to mis-construct the first three-and-a-bit rows of the periodic table.

A less chemically blasphemous version was provided in a link in the comments. However, that version uses deprecated code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcounter{atomicnumber}
\setcounter{atomicnumber}{0}
\tikzset{%
  element/.pic={%
    \tikzset{%
      elements/.cd,
      #1,
      /tikz/.cd,
    }%
    \stepcounter{atomicnumber}%
    % addaswyd o gôd Enrico Maria De Angelis:
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339005/
    \node (\elementsymbol) [font=\huge\elementfont, text=\elementtext, inner sep=.5*\elementsep, anchor=mid, fill=\elementfill, rounded corners=2pt, minimum size=\elementsize] {\strut\elementsymbol};
    \node [font=\tiny\elementfont, text=\elementtext, inner sep=2pt, anchor=north west] at (\elementsymbol.north west) {\theatomicnumber};
    \node [font=\tiny\elementfont, text=\elementtext, inner sep=2pt, anchor=south] at (\elementsymbol.south) {\elementname};
  },
  elements/.search also={/tikz},
  elements/.cd,
  name/.store in=\elementname,
  font/.store in=\elementfont,
  text/.store in=\elementtext,
  fill/.store in=\elementfill,
  symbol/.store in=\elementsymbol,
  size/.store in=\elementsize,
  sep/.store in=\elementsep,
  name=Full Name,
  font=\sffamily,
  text=white,
  fill=black,
  symbol=Sy,
  size=35pt,
  sep=2.5pt,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=\elementsize]
  \coordinate (o);
  \foreach \k/\m [count=\elementrow, evaluate=\elementrow as \elementshift using {-\elementrow*(\elementsize+\elementsep)}] in {%
    magenta/{H/Hydrogen,He/Helium},
    cyan/{%
      Li/Lithium,Be/Beryllium,B/Boron,C/Carbon,Ny/Nitrogen,
      O/Oxygen,F/Fluorine,Ne/Neon%
    },
    blue!50!cyan/{%
      Na/Sodium,Mg/Magnesium,Al/Aluminium,Si/Silicon,P/Phosphorous,
      S/Sulphur,Cl/Chlorine,Ar/Argon%
    },
    blue/{K/Potassium,Ca/Calcium}%
  }{%
    \coordinate (o\elementrow) at (0,\elementshift pt);
    \begin{scope}
      \foreach \i/\j [remember=\i as \ilast (initially o\elementrow)] in \m
      \pic [right=\elementsize+\elementsep of \ilast.mid] {element={name=\j, symbol=\i, fill=\k}};
    \end{scope}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: chemical blasphemy]

Comment: +1 looks great. But could you edit your code so that the elements of `\foreach` are better grouped by adding some linebreaks? If you don't want to do it, I'll be happy to do it myself, if you are ok with this.

Comment: @StefanPinnow They are grouped according to their rows in the periodic table. If you have different content, you just create the groups differently when setting up the loop, but I'm not going to do that with this content - it is already chemical blasphemy. I'm not going to make it into chemical heresy as well!

Comment: @StefanPinnow The real issue is the horizontal spacing i.e. the lack of gaps between elements which should be separated by space. However, since that is not required by the OP's image, I decided it was not worth figuring out a neat way of doing it here. (But I would quite like to do this when I get time or steal time.)

Comment: What I mean is, that code line starting with `\foreach` is veeeeeeery long and so -- at least for me -- hard to read. I just wanted to insert some linebreaks to the code and not change the content ...

Comment: @StefanPinnow Oh, sorry. I completely misunderstood. I've added some - is that enough? Please add some more if not. I've broken the lines by groups to keep the code for each row together as that seemed logical to me.

Comment: That was good. I have added some more linebreaks also to the rest of the code. For me that is much more readable than (very) long lines. (But of course that may be personal preference.) If you don't like it, just revert it.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Why have you removed the comment signs? In my experience, Ti*k*Z can be very fussy about spaces. Did you test the code? I'm not keen on indenting everything. I don't like this many breaks as it makes it harder for me to read. I have a small screen so I try to use the width of it!

Comment: Yes, I did test the code and "your" and "my" version give the same output. Only this one `%` sign after "Calcium" is really needed. As I said, if you like your version more than mine you are free to revert the changes. But on this site I think the code window will not get much wider than around 100 characters, so at least here it helps to not scroll down *and* to the right ;)

Comment: @StefanPinnow I guess we differ in what we find readable/intelligible, so I'm afraid I've undone some of your changes. I can only view around 33 lines at a time and I guess my preference is to be able to see a bit more of the code I'm working on. And I really don't like lines with only comment symbols :-). But I have left some extra space in the `\foreach` lines - I agree that it makes it easier to see what is happening in that case. Although it works without commenting the spaces, I've played safe rather than sorry ....

Answer (score 7):

This is just one tile.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Dv
    \coordinate (dv) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (base) at (35pt,0pt);
    \coordinate (height) at (0pt,35pt);
    \coordinate (diag) at ($(base)+(height)$);
    \fill[rounded corners=2pt, magenta] ($(dv)-.5*(diag)$) rectangle +(diag); 
    \node[white] at (dv) {\sffamily\huge Dv};
    \node[white, inner sep=2pt] (dvtext) at ($(dv)-.5*(height)$) [anchor=south] {\sffamily\tiny Diversification};
    \node[white, inner sep=2pt] (dvnum) at ($(dv)+.5*(height)-.5*(base)$) [anchor=north west] {\sffamily\tiny 01};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It should be easy to copy, paste and modify a lot of times. To put them together the commands `\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}` should be enough.

Comment: Just put it in a pic with multiple arguments