# How to draw a grid of squares with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to reproduce in `tikz` the following image[image] I tried with the command

```
\matrix[nodes = {draw,ultra thick},row sep=0.2cm,column sep=0.2cm{

\node[rectangle] {};
...

};
```

However what I get is not really adaptable to what I want.

**After comment update**: what I have done until now (far from what I want) is

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
 \tikzstyle{ann} = [draw=none,fill=none,right]
 \matrix[nodes={draw, ultra thick, color=blue},
    row sep=0.2cm,column sep=0.2cm] {
 \node[rectangle] {}; &
 \node[rectangle] {}; &
 \node[rectangle] {};&
 \node[rectangle] {};\\
 \node[rectangle] {}; &
 \node[rectangle] {}; &
 \node[rectangle] {};&
 \node[rectangle] {};\\
 \node[rectangle] {}; &
 \node[rectangle] {}; &
 \node[rectangle] {};&
 \node[rectangle] {};\\
 \node[rectangle] {}; &
 \node[rectangle] {}; &
 \node[rectangle] {};&
 \node[rectangle] {};\\    };
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: of course I want the image without the watermark

Comment: This is a do-it-for-me task. Please show what you've got so far and then ask a specific question.

Comment: The following question should probably get you going: [Periodic table tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/337845/2693).

Comment: You can have a look at the `ticket` package [http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/ticket/doc/manual.pdf].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By use of `matrix` and quite sophisticated definitions used for nodes, I managed to obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, matrix}
\makeatletter
 \def\tikzsavelastnodename#1{\let#1=\tikz@last@fig@name}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
  \tikzset{
add text/.style args = {#1:#2}{
        append after command={node[inner sep=2mm, font=\footnotesize\sffamily,
                                   anchor=#1]
        at (\tikzsavednodename.#1) {#2}}
                                },
add left text/.style args = {#1:#2}{
        append after command={node[inner sep=0pt, font=\footnotesize\sffamily,
                rotate around={+90:($(+2mm,2mm)+(\tikzsavednodename.#1)$)}]
        at (\tikzsavednodename.#1) {#2}}
                                },
add right text/.style args = {#1:#2}{
        append after command={node[inner sep=0pt, font=\footnotesize\sffamily,
                rotate around={-90:($(-2mm,2mm)+(\tikzsavednodename.#1)$)}]
        at (\tikzsavednodename.#1) {#2}}
                                },
saveLNN/.style = {append after command={%
        \pgfextra{\tikzsavelastnodename\tikzsavednodename}},#1},
MN/.style args = {#1/#2}{% Matrix Nodes
    draw, rounded corners=5mm, ultra thick, color=#1,
    minimum size=32mm, outer sep=1mm,
    font=\fontsize{32}{16}\bfseries\color{#1}\selectfont,
    align=center,
    node contents={#2\\[\baselineskip]~},
    saveLNN},
           }

    \matrix[matrix of nodes,
%            ampersand replacement=\&,
            row sep=1mm,column sep=1mm] 
{
 \node[MN=cyan/ISTJ,
       add text=north: text below top,
       add text=south: text above bottom,
       add left text =west: rotated text left,
       add right text=east: rotated text right
       ];   &
 \node[MN=cyan/ISFJ,
       add text=north: text below top,
       add text=south: text above bottom,
       add left text =west: rotated text left,
       add right text=east: rotated text right
       ];   \\
};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I didn't bother with actual texts at node borders, with node size (I not recommend use `scale`, better is change `minim um size` and size of used fonts).

That MWE will really minimal, in matrix I only consider two cells. Other you can add on showed way.

**Addendum:**
First solution is unnecessary complicated (base on one mine old universal solution), so for this case, where anchor for side text are the same in all nodes, the above solution can be significantly simplified:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, matrix}

\newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
ST/.style = {font=\footnotesize\sffamily, text=#1},
MN/.style args = {#1/% color
                  #2/% main text
                  #3/% top text
                  #4/% bottom text
                  #5/% left text
                  #6%
                  }{% Matrix Nodes
    draw =#1, rounded corners=5mm, line width=1mm,
    minimum size=32mm, outer sep=1mm,
    font=\fontsize{32}{16}\bfseries\color{#1}\selectfont,
    align=center,
    node contents={#2\\[\baselineskip]~},
    path picture={%
    \node[ST=#1,yshift=-3mm] at (\ppbb.north)  {#3};
    \node[ST=#1,yshift=+2mm] at (\ppbb.south)  {#4};
    \node[ST=#1,rotate around={+90:($(+1.5mm,1.5mm)+(\ppbb.west)$)}]
          at (\ppbb.west) {#5};
    \node[ST=#1,rotate around={-90:($(-1.5mm,1.5mm)+(\ppbb.east)$)}]
          at (\ppbb.east) {#6};
                    }%  end path picture
                    }%% end of MN
                        ]
\matrix[matrix of nodes,
            row sep=0.1mm, column sep=0.1mm] 
{
\node[MN=cyan/ISTJ/text below top/text above bottom%
        /rotated text left/rotated text right];
    &
\node[MN=purple/ISFJ/text below top/text above bottom%
        /rotated text left/rotated text right];    \\
};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In this solution for anchors of side texts are used `path picture bounding box`. The result of new code (which determine thicker node borders and colored side texts) is:

[image]

Comment: I think that your complex `add ... text` could be replaced by conveniently anchored and rotated labels. Am I missing any reason for them?

Comment: yes, it can be. i adopt one my older similar solution, which is so complicated some some other reason. I can/will in next step make for user simpler solution (in the first spare time).

Comment: I find the spare time and wrote new solution, which is (for use) far more concise  as the first one.

Comment: Nice solution, I haven't tought about `path picture`. My solution consisted in defining four styles like `lleft/.style={label={[mylabel, anchor=north, rotate=90]180:#1}}` (and similars for the other three sides) which can be added as node options: `\node[lleft={Text on left side}, lright, ...];`.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to complet my comments on Zarko's answer. Following code uses Zarko's code, but all text in nodes is placed using `labels` with convenient `anchors`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        ST/.style = {font=\footnotesize\sffamily, text=#1},
        MN/.style args = {%
            #1/% color
            #2/% main text
            #3/% top text
            #4/% bottom text
            #5/% left text
            #6%  right text
        }{% Matrix Nodes
            draw =#1, rounded corners=5mm, line width=1mm,
            minimum size=32mm, outer sep=1mm,
            align=center,
            label={[above=7mm, text=#1, font=\fontsize{32}{16}\bfseries\selectfont]center:#2},
            label={[ST=#1, anchor=north, below=1mm]north:#3},
            label={[ST=#1, anchor=south, above=1mm]south:#4},
            label={[ST=#1, rotate=90, anchor=north, below=1mm]west:#5},
            label={[ST=#1, rotate=270, anchor=north, below=1mm]east:#6},
        },%% end of MN
        MN/.default={cyan/ISTJ/text below top/text above bottom/rotated text left/rotated text right},
]

\matrix[row sep=1pt, column sep=1pt]{
\node[MN]{};
&
\node[MN=red/ISFJ/text below top/text above bottom/rotated text left/rotated text right]{};
\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice completeness! (+1)