# TikZ: generic position of label with variable text at node corner

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to create a style in TikZ that draws a node with a label in the above left corner.

The problem is, that the label text and the node width should be variable.
Below is a minimal example (my current approach), where the position of the label of the last node (nodename3) is incorrect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{genericnode/.style={rectangle, rounded corners=2pt, draw=black},
             mystyle/.style={genericnode, text width=15mm, fill=red!50,
                             label={[anchor=west, yshift=3pt, xshift=-9mm]{\tiny #1}}},
             vll/.style={mystyle=VeryLongLabel},
             sl/.style={mystyle=ShortL},}

    \node[vll]                                           (nodename)  {\tt text};
    \node[sl, below = 1cm of nodename]                   (nodename2) {\tt node with more lines};
    \node[sl, below = 1cm of nodename2, text width=35mm] (nodename3) {\tt node with more lines};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See, if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360522/ can be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set an `alias` name for the main node and use this name in the label options to position the label node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    genericnode/.style={rectangle, rounded corners=2pt, draw=black,},
    mystyle/.style={
      genericnode, text width=15mm, fill=red!50,
      alias=genericnode,% <- alias added
      label={[anchor=south west,shift={(genericnode.north west)},inner sep=2pt]{\tiny #1}}% position the label using the alias 
    },
    vll/.style={mystyle=VeryLongLabel},
    sl/.style={mystyle=ShortL},}

  \node[vll] (nodename) {\texttt{text}};
  \node[sl, below = 1cm of nodename] (nodename2) {\texttt{node with more lines}};
  \node[sl, below = 1cm of nodename2, text width=35mm] (nodename3) {\texttt{node with more lines}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I guess node contents for both is also an option.