# tikz change color based on argument

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, calculations

I'm trying to produce a periodic table where the color of the elements changes based on their electronegativity, like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity#Electronegativities_of_the_elements).

Thanks to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339005/30912), I can create the table (first two rows) like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\element}[5]{%
        \coordinate (el) at (#2,-#3);
        \coordinate (base) at ($(.95,0)$);
        \coordinate (height) at ($(0,.95)$);
        \coordinate (diag) at ($(base)+(height)$);
        \filldraw[rounded corners, fill=yellow!0.55!red] ($(el)-.5*(diag)$) rectangle +(diag);
        \node[white] at (el) {\sffamily\Large \strut#1};
        \node[white, inner sep=2pt] (en) at ($(el)-.5*(height)$) [anchor=south] {\sffamily\tiny #5};
        \node[white, inner sep=2pt] (atnum) at ($(el)+.5*(height)-.5*(base)$) [anchor=north west] {\sffamily\tiny #4};
    }

    \newcommand{\grayelement}[5]{%
        \coordinate (el) at (#2,-#3);
        \coordinate (base) at ($(.95,0)$);
        \coordinate (height) at ($(0,.95)$);
        \coordinate (diag) at ($(base)+(height)$);
        \filldraw[rounded corners, fill=gray!70] ($(el)-.5*(diag)$) rectangle +(diag);
        \node[white] at (el) {\sffamily\Large \strut#1};
        \node[white, inner sep=2pt] (en) at ($(el)-.5*(height)$) [anchor=south] {\sffamily\tiny #5};
        \node[white, inner sep=2pt] (atnum) at ($(el)+.5*(height)-.5*(base)$) [anchor=north west] {\sffamily\tiny #4};
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \element{H}{1}{1}{1}{2.20}
        \grayelement{He}{18}{1}{2}{--}

        \element{Li}{1}{2}{3}{0.98}
        \element{Be}{2}{2}{4}{1.57}
        \element{B}{13}{2}{5}{2.04}
        \element{C}{14}{2}{6}{2.55}
        \element{N}{15}{2}{7}{3.04}
        \element{O}{16}{2}{8}{3.44}
        \element{F}{17}{2}{9}{3.98}
        \grayelement{Ne}{18}{2}{10}{--}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to do something like `fill=yellow!#5/4!red`, but I can't figure out how to do it. #5 is the argument for the electronegativity, and I want to divide by 4 because the highest electronegativity is 3.98

Comment: Does not that mean that you want to divide all `#5` values by 4? Or when it exceeds a certain value. Please make this clear.

Comment: @Masroor The OP wants to divide a value by its maximum to find a percentage, see my answer.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Yes, I was guessing that much. I wanted to make it sure before I try to find a solution. And your answer is an excellent one. As they always are.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `#5/4*100` in a `\pgfmathsetmacro`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\element}[5]{%
        \coordinate (el) at (#2,-#3);
        \coordinate (base) at ($(.95,0)$);
        \coordinate (height) at ($(0,.95)$);
        \coordinate (diag) at ($(base)+(height)$);                 
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myperc}{#5/4*100}
        \filldraw[rounded corners, fill=yellow!\myperc!red] ($(el)-.5*(diag)$) rectangle +(diag);
        \node[white] at (el) {\sffamily\Large \strut#1};
        \node[white, inner sep=2pt] (en) at ($(el)-.5*(height)$) [anchor=south] {\sffamily\tiny #5};
        \node[white, inner sep=2pt] (atnum) at ($(el)+.5*(height)-.5*(base)$) [anchor=north west] {\sffamily\tiny #4};
    }

    \newcommand{\grayelement}[5]{%
        \coordinate (el) at (#2,-#3);
        \coordinate (base) at ($(.95,0)$);
        \coordinate (height) at ($(0,.95)$);
        \coordinate (diag) at ($(base)+(height)$);
        \filldraw[rounded corners, fill=gray!70] ($(el)-.5*(diag)$) rectangle +(diag);
        \node[white] at (el) {\sffamily\Large \strut#1};
        \node[white, inner sep=2pt] (en) at ($(el)-.5*(height)$) [anchor=south] {\sffamily\tiny #5};
        \node[white, inner sep=2pt] (atnum) at ($(el)+.5*(height)-.5*(base)$) [anchor=north west] {\sffamily\tiny #4};
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \element{H}{1}{1}{1}{2.20}
        \grayelement{He}{18}{1}{2}{--}

        \element{Li}{1}{2}{3}{0.98}
        \element{Be}{2}{2}{4}{1.57}
        \element{B}{13}{2}{5}{2.04}
        \element{C}{14}{2}{6}{2.55}
        \element{N}{15}{2}{7}{3.04}
        \element{O}{16}{2}{8}{3.44}
        \element{F}{17}{2}{9}{3.98}
        \grayelement{Ne}{18}{2}{10}{--}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]